# I want to make a fastest file sharing app through Wi-Fi for android, i want to compress data while transfer to increase speed

Tags: c#

I want to replace big data (in Gb) with small chunks (in Mb or Kb) while wireless transfer of files (Wi-Fi), I want to increase the speed of large files transfer.

I tried to replace data by gray code but I can't write proper c# code due to lack of knowledge.

```
 using System; 

class GFG { 

    static int binary_to_gray(int n, int i) 
    {  
        int a, b; 
        int result = 0; 
        if (n != 0)  
        { 

            a = n % 10;  

            n = n / 10; 

            b = n % 10;  

            if ((a & ~ b) == 1 || (~ a & b) == 1)  
            { 
                result = (int) (result + Math.Pow(10,i)); 
            } 

            return binary_to_gray(n, ++i) + result; 
        } 

        return 0; 
    }

    public static void Main() 
    { 
        int binary_number; 
        binary_number = 1011101; 

        Console.WriteLine(binary_to_gray(binary_number,0)); 
    }  
}
```

I don't have Computer Science Subject in school, so I try to learn programming by my own, its my hobby, I'm working on file sharing app through Wi-Fi for android.
I expected to compress data but it remains same or increase.

Comment: You can look [here](https://www.sanfoundry.com/csharp-programs-create-gray-code/)

Answer (score 1):

[Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) is not a compression algorithm. It's an algorithm to reduce the number of bit changes. Thus it will not reduce the size of the file transfer.

To me it seems you want a [lossless compression algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Lossless) like LZ or LZW (known from compression programs like ZIP).

Comment: thanks for helping me ^_^   can you tell that how much it will compress in approximate percentage?

Comment: I want to compress things on binary level and ready to go (no or least processing time). how can I do it using c#?

Comment: @MikkuGray: the compression percentage heavily depends on the data you transmit. If you compress encrypted data (like a Veracrypt container), the effect is 0%. If you compress already compressed data (like a ZIP or RAR file), it's likely 0% as well. MP3 and JPG will not compress well. For plain text, it's maybe 60%. You really can't say in advance. Get a ZIP utility like 7Zip and compress the data you want to send. With C# you can get the same using the [GZipStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.8)